# How to return a specific page without reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I am trying to develop a mobile application using Javascript. I would like to make a link that allows you to return to a specific page that is already visited without reloading this page.

I tried with this code:

```
$('#ajouter').live('click',function(e) {
  window.localStorage.setItem("phrase", $("label[for='" + ($('input[name=opt1]:checked').attr('id') ) + "']").text());
  //Id Rubrique
  $.mobile.changePage('../z.html');
});
$("#z").live('pageshow', function() {
  .....
}
```

But it makes me reload the page.

Comment: just a thought - you may save yourself a lot of headache with cross-device and cross-OS optimizations by using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: If you're using jQuery > 1.7 then live() is a deprecated function. Use the on() handler instead...

Comment: @jtheman : i should be change my code of page like this

`$("#z").on('pageshow', function() {
  .....
}`

Comment: No for use of the live() equivalent use $(document).on('pageshow','#z', function() - or limiting 'document' to closer parent element

Comment: @jtheman `$(document).on('pageshow','#z', function(){...}`   and with this code my page does not refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('body').on('click','#ajouter',function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // stops default behaviour ie reloading
  ...
```

Also suggested change to on() function instead of live()

NOTE if you're using jQuery version prior to 1.8 then KEEP the live() handler as in the question, just add preventDefault:

```
$('#ajouter').live('click',function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: `$('body').on('click','#ajouter',function(e) 
  {
    e.preventDefault(); // stops default behaviour ie reloa
    window.localStorage.setItem("phrase", $("label[for='" + ( $('input[name=opt1]:checked').attr('id') ) + "']").text());       //Id Rubrique
    $.mobile.changePage('../prestation_html/etape'+window.localStorage.getItem("id_grp")+'.html');
  }`
`


`$(document).on('pageshow','#A1', function(){...}`

Comment: should be working but just add  e.preventDefault(); to your previous code (the click handler)...

Comment: yes with ypour last code is good but now :( i have new problem :(  
the page that contains the button `ajouter` (Page 2) contained is added dynamically, my problem when I come back again on page 2,the page 2 displays the previous page without changing the contained

Comment: Maybe you need to add a new question for this with new code. Its hard for me to see your problem and to discuss within comments...

Comment: Please mark this as your suggsted answer, that is your way of saying thank you here at SO...

Comment: Just beside the top of MY answer is a zero with arrows, just under that you can set a green tick, that means you think this is the best answer for your question... Thanks!

Comment: i dont have a permission beacause i'am new here and my reputation = 1, may be you can up my reputation with up my question

Comment: Yes you DO have permission to check the answer BUT NOT to upvote the answer. If you just try to check the green tick BELOW the number/arrows then it will work. Also You will earn a few scores from ticking the answer! See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask for more info... Thanks!

Comment: ah ok, i understand now sorry :)

can you help me here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623222/contained-not-exchanged

Answer (score 0):

make the function return false to avoid the default behavior of reloading the page

Comment: how do I write the function?

Comment: `$('body').on('click','#ajouter',function(e) 
  {
    e.preventDefault(); // stops default behaviour ie reloa
    window.localStorage.setItem("phrase", $("label[for='" + ( $('input[name=opt1]:checked').attr('id') ) + "']").text());       //Id Rubrique
    $.mobile.changePage('../prestation_html/etape'+window.localStorage.getItem("id_grp")+'.html');
  }`
`


`$(document).on('pageshow','#A1', function(){...}`

Comment: make the last statement in your function as return false;

Comment: now :( i have new problem :( the page that contains the button ajouter (Page 2) contained is added dynamically, my problem when I come back again on page 2,the page 2 displays the previous page without changing the contained